# Difference between indefinite and definite integration: $\int f(x) \;dx = \int^x_0 f(x) \; dx$?

Tags: calculus

$\int f(x) \;dx = \int^x_0 f(x) \; dx$

---

I sometimes get the impression that there's meant to be a basic and important difference between definite and indefinite integration. But when I consider simple examples, it seems to me like the equation in the title holds, which makes it seem like there's not much difference.

Comment: Probably best to use $\int f(x)dx=\int_0^xf(t)dt$ where $t$ is a "dummy" variable.

Answer (score 3):

Definite integration gives, in principle, a definite real number back (if the upper bound happens to contain a variable, you get a function, but still).

Indefinite integration is usually interpreted to mean antidifferentiation, through the power of the fundamental theorem of calculus. It gives back a whole family of functions, with an unknown / generic constant term.

So in theory, these are quite different operations, and it's only through the miracle of FtC that they are so closely related (and thus get very similar notations). I have even heard people go so far as to say there is no such thing as indefinite integrals, there are only definite integrals and antiderivatives.

At any rate they are most definitely not equal. Best case, $\int_0^x f(t)\,dt$ (please don't use $x$ both as integration bound and integration variable) is *one of the many* $\int f(x)\,dx$.

Comment: The notation I used was meant to signify "the integral of $f(x)$ on the interval $[0,x]$", which seemed to me to be equivalent to the indefinite integral. That "there is no such thing as indefinite integrals, there are only definite integrals and antiderivatives" may be the answer I'm looking for.

Comment: @mjc Note that integrating $f(x)$ on the interval $[0,x]$ makes no sense. As I said, please don't use $x$ as both a bound and as the integration variable.

Comment: Why does it make no sense?

Comment: @mjc Let's pick a concrete example, like $f(x) = x^2$. Then saying that you are interested in the behavior of $x^2$ on the interval from $0$ to $x$ is a statement with way too many $x$'s in it.

Comment: My reasoning is this: the area enclosed between $x^2$ and the x-axis is $\frac{1^3}{3}$ at $x=1$, $\frac{2^3}{3}$ at $x=2$, and in general $\frac{x^3}{3}(+c)$ at $x=x$. Isn't that how the indefinite quality is captured?

Comment: Yes, but you have too many $x$'s. Look at "at $x = x$", for instance. That's not a single point at the real axis. That's anywhere, always. You need to have one variable for the function input, and a different variable for the bound.

Comment: "That's not a single point at the real axis. That's anywhere, always.": exactly; it's indefinite. What am I missing?

Comment: Let's look at sums instead, see if it's easier to see the problem there. What would $\sum_{n = 1}^nn^2$ mean? $\int_0^x x^2\,dx$ has basically the same issue.

Comment: I think I've reached the point where I'll have to go away and digest the conversation so far. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $a$ is a value for which the definite integral $\int_a^xf(t)dt$ is well-defined; it is then a function of $x$. You can't write $\int_a^x f(x) dx$, because $x$ is the argument of this function, while $t$ is a *dummy variable*. You must write $\int_a^xf(t)dt$ instead of $\int_a^xf(x)dx$, just as one writes $\sum_{k=a}^xf(k)$ instead of $\sum_{x=a}^xf(x)$.

For such an $a$, $\int f(x)dx$ is shorthand for the set $\left\{C+\int_a^xf(t)dt|C\in S\right\}$ of functions (where $S$ is a number system of interest, such as $\Bbb R$ or $\Bbb C$), or (if the context permits) an arbitrary function in this set if we don't care which one we're talking about.

Comment: This may be a dumb question, but what's the difference between $\int^b_a f(x) \; dx$ and $\int^x_a f(t) \; dt$?

Comment: @mjc If $F$ is an antiderivative of $f$, one is $F(b)-F(a)$ while the other is $F(x)-F(a)$. But the former requires $x$ to be a dummy variable, in which case the latter is undefined outside of the dummy variable scope.

Comment: You say $x$ is a dummy variable in the expression $\int^b_a f(x) \; dx$? Does that mean the variable to be integrated is always a dummy?

Comment: @mjc Yes, like the $k$ in $\sum_{k=1}^nk=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$.

Comment: If I can think out loud for a moment, we could equally write that as $\sum_{k_{initial}=1}^{k_{final}}k=\frac{k_{final}(k_{final}+1)}{2}$.

Comment: @mjc I think you mean $$\sum_{k_{initial}}^{k_{final}}k=\frac{k_{final}(k_{final}+1)-k_{initial}(k_{initial}-1)}{2}$$. The final result cannot depend on $k$, *because it's a dummy variable*. (Incidentally, I typed that as `\sum_{k_{initial}}^{k_{final}}k=\frac{k_{final}(k_{final}+1)-k_{initial}(k_{initial}-1)}{2}`.)

Comment: I'm going to have to go away and think about that, but I think this is getting to the nub of the issue, so thanks for that.

Comment: Would it be fair to call the interval $[a,b]$ the domain of an integral $\int^b_a f(x) \; dx$?

Comment: @mjc It's called the integration range. Domains are properties of a function. Of course, you're welcome to define a function of domain $[a,\,b]$ equal to $\int_a^xf(t)dt$, but why would you want such a domain restriction?

Answer (score 0):

1. The **definite integral** of $f(x)$ is a **NUMBER** and represents
   the area under the curve f(x) from $x=a$ to $x=b$.

   A definite integral has upper and lower limits on the integrals, and
   it’s called definite because, at the end of the problem, we have a
   number – it is a *definite answer*.
2. The **indefinite integral** of $f(x)$ is a **FUNCTION**.

   Indefinite integral usually gives a general solution to the
   differential equation.

   The indefinite integral is more of a general form of integration,
   and it can be interpreted as the *anti-derivative* of the considered
   function.

---

**Fundamental Theorem of Calculus**

The definite and the indefinite integral are linked by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus as follows: In order to compute a definite integral, find the indefinite integral (also known as the anti-derivative) of the function and evaluate at the endpoints x=a and x=b.

***The difference between definite and indefinite integrals will be evident once we evaluate the integrals for the same function.***

Please check following source for more detail: [1](http://www.differencebetween.net/science/mathematics-statistics/difference-between-definite-and-indefinite-integrals/) [2](https://socratic.org/questions/what-is-the-difference-between-a-definite-and-indefinite-integral)